# Export from SQL to Flat file Chinese charaters

Tags: mysql, export

I am attempting to export a SQL table to a flat file via the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. The table consists of doubles and words (in both the rows  and columns), instead of getting a clean output I get a flat file filled with Chinese. What formatting do I need to change in my Flat file manager set up. I am completely confused.

thanks in advance

Comment: or what looks like Chinese, could be Kanji perhaps

Comment: You need to select Unicode encoding for the sql export. Problem solved